# Ajax x SEO (Mecanismos de Busca)

Tags: php, ajax, google, seo

Bom, será que o *Google* (ou outro motor de busca) avalia a página quando ela termina de carregar ou ela apenas pega a cópia HTML gerada (pagina gerada dinamicamente, PHP por exemplo) e faz sua análise?

Tenho um documento que executa *4* chamadas Ajax para carregar informações (detalhes do produto, descrição deste, produtos semelhantes e comentários) logo após o `DOM` ter sido carregado.

Essas informações são importantes para a pesquisa, pois elas podem interferir no *rank* da página (são informações do produto..).

Ouvi falar do `pushState()`, que cria um novo ponto no histórico, alterando a URL atual sem atualizar a página, e vi gente relacionando isso como boa prática para Ajax se relacionar bem com aos motores de busca, mas estou confuso em relação ao uso.

Answer (score -1):

Geralmente o Motor de busca não acha o conteúdo carregado via AJAX, uma solução para este problema seria: Construir uma estrutura de links e diretórios as quais os motores de busca possam navegar. Isso resolve duas situações: a própria navegação do motor de busca; e a navegação do usuário, que, para fins de agilidade possa querer acessar diretamente um conteúdo específico do site, através do link, coisa que o ajax por si só não permite, uma vez que ele não muda a URL enquanto se usa o site.

**Links do conteúdo completo**

[AJAX x SEO PT-br](http://www.agenciamestre.com/seo/ajax-e-seo/)

[Discussão do mesmo assunto no Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-br/izdyrBs-Emo)

[AJAX x SEO Inglês](http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/news/2122137/googlebot-learns-read-ajax-javascript-comments)

Comment: Como?.. Minha requisição AJAX obtem a resposta de uma página PHP no qual ela executa uma consulta no banco de dados e retorna a informação que pedi.
Eu poderia colocar tudo na página e entregar pro cliente, sem precisar usar AJAX, mas com AJAX eu(acredito..) que consigo entregar a página mais rápida já que o servidor não tem o trabalho de ficar processando tudo só pra depois o cliente visualizar a página, e sim que durante a visualização vá carregando as informações do produto(todas elas são requisitadas de forma assíncrona quando o DOM carrega).